# How to set an arrow-style function as a default parameter for Input()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, class-fields

So I have a component that displays rows of data in a table. I have an input for the function that should run if someone double clicks a row. I want to default that to doing something with the router.

This works fine:

```
@Input() rowDoubleClickedFunction: (result: T) => void = this.routeToDetailsPage;
private routeToDetailsPage(result: T) {
    this.router.navigate(['route here']);
}
```

This is abbreviated to get the point across. I'm really doing some other things in the function before making the router call. But as soon as I change the bottom function to the arrow syntax:

```
@Input() rowDoubleClickedFunction: (result: T) => void = this.routeToDetailsPage;
private routeToDetailsPage = (result: T) => {
    //Something more complicated with "this" which necessitates using arrow syntax        
    this.router.navigate(['route composed from code above']);
};
```

I get an error:
Property 'routeToDetailsPage' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)

It doesn't appear to be an issue with the linter. Is there a way to do this or am I out of luck?

Comment: If it's an arrow function, you can't use `this` inside it anyways (it points to `globalThis`).

Comment: @vr. No? This is part of a `class` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class fields are evaluated in order. You're doing

```
@Input()
public rowDoubleClickedFunction = this.routeToDetailsPage;
private routeToDetailsPage = …;
```

which accesses the `routeToDetailsPage` property before it is initialised. Flip them around:

```
private routeToDetailsPage = (result: T) => {
    …
};
@Input()
rowDoubleClickedFunction: (result: T) => void = this.routeToDetailsPage;
```

or if you're not using `routeToDetailsPage` anywhere else, just drop it entirely and write only

```
@Input()
rowDoubleClickedFunction: (result: T) => void = (result: T) => {
    …
};
```

Comment: I swear I tried this already and it still errored, but when I tried it again to see what the error message was, it worked. Thanks!